# When doing runserver, keep getting new data loaded in my database

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-settings

Every time I do a: `python manage.py runserver`

And I load the site, python gets data and puts this in my database.
Even when I already filled some info in the database. Enough to get a view of what I am working on.
Now it is not loading the information I want and instead putting in new information to add to the database so it can work with some data.

What is the reason my data in the database is not being processed?
And how do I stop new data being loaded into the database.

Answer (score 0):

May be it is happening due to migration file first sometimes when you migrate models into database query language with same number
python manage.py makemigrations 0001
This "0001" has to be changed everytime
To solve your problem once delete the migrations file and then again migrate all models and then try
Tell if this work